# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] failed to upload image

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've trying for three hours to figure this error (`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] failed to upload image`). Here my code i haven't found yet my problem:

```
app.post('/posts/store',(req,res)=>{
  let image = req.files.image;
  image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'public/img', image.name), async(error)=>{
      await BlogPost.create({
          ...req.body,
          image:'/img/' + image.name
      });
      res.redirect('/');
   
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figure out what worng , to many http header req because the redirect was inside my async func (;